# Automatically show symbol value for xml atribute in IntelliJ

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

tl;dr show evaluated symbol expression (pointing to android resource files) in xml files in IntelliJ

I started default android project in **IntelliJ Idea 14.1.2**
When I navigate to `layout/fragment_main.xml` I can see that some *symbol* is evaluated:
see line 7 - grey font
[image]

When I place caret on value I can see *symbol* expression:
[image]

Finally when I click value it turns to symbol expression:
[image]

How to make it look like before - evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action is called `Fold selection / remove region` and the default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and type `Fold selection`.